R Shiny app running in Quirks mode, how to disable it?
When deploying a Shiny app inside an iframe, I get the warning that "Page layout may be unexpected due to Quirks Mode". This doesn't happen when running locally.
How can I disable this?
One suggestion is to force DOCTYPE to be , can this be done in Shiny?
